# Heterogeneous Map in Scala, is it possible?

Tags: scala, dictionary, shapeless, heterogeneous

So the problem is in title. Here r some exaplanations:
As we know, we can use `HList` to store objects with its types.

```
SomeCL[Int], SomeCL[String], SomeCL[MyType1] :: ... :: HNil
```

Where `SomeCL` is some class. So I want to make make map, which can store information about all types inside, smth like:

```
// it is wrong usage of HMap, it is an example of how I want it be
HMap("string1" -> SomeCL[Int], "string2" -> SomeCL[MyType1], ... )
```

And not to loose information about types. I want to notice, that object types and number of objects r unknown, so we cant use lots of implicits for native shapeless `HMap`. Is it possible?

**EDITED**

(I meant that we have no possibility to write manually all implicit type convertions for shapeless `HMap`)

P.S.

If it is not possible, how can i decide such problem: For example I have some objects in `HList`, and I am building graph. It is very important to safe type of each node (we create nodes from objects in `HList`), and I dont know the number of objects. How can i build graph, and not to loose information about types?

**EDITED2**

Btw, this code will throw an error, if `S` is the super type of `A` and `C`; how can we avoid this?

```
class SomeCL[T](val l: T) {

}

class NodeMap[K, V]

implicit val si = new NodeMap[String, SomeCL[A]]
implicit val sd = new NodeMap[String, SomeCL[S]]
implicit val sb = new NodeMap[String, SomeCL[C]]

val hm = HMap[NodeMap]("foo" -> new SomeCL(new A), "bar" -> new SomeCL(new S), "lol" -> new SomeCL(new C))
```

Comment: Any progress? It seems as I have the same questions. In my case `SomeCL[T]` is a little bit more complex (e.g. it has a HMap) and hence I'm not able to create the implicits manually :) Would be nice if the compiler could infer it.

Comment: @user3127060 can you ask a separate question or to provide more info?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it's provided for you in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).
See [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3a-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps).

Comment: thx for reply, y, I tried to use implicits for shapeless `HMap`, but it throws error (try example in my post above, after `edited2`); I tried to make smth like : `val hmap = ("string1" ->> 3) :: ("string2" ->> true) :: ("string3" ->> boolean) :: HNil; hmap("string1");` mb it will help, I'll test it a little later, mb it suits me :) I'll write results.

Answer (score 0):

> that object types and number of objects r unknown

Then you cannot use compile time type information, obviously... You need to reconstruct types dynamically, using for example pattern matching

Comment: mm, they r known ofcource before compile, but I meant that we have no possibility to write manually all implicit type convertions for shapeless `HMap` (for `BiMapIS`). btw u mb answered my question, im idiot, mb I should and I can write implicits.